# Read KML file with GDAL/OGR for Python

Tags: python, gdal, kml, ogr

I have file : test.kml and I try to open it with GDAL/OGR (1.6) librairie in Python (2.5).

But I don't succed can you help me ?

This is my code :

```
from osgeo import ogr

adresse = 'test.kml'
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('KML')
datasource = driver.Open(adresse)
layer = datasource.GetLayer()
layerDefn = layer.GetLayerDefn()
featDefn = layer.GetLayerDefn()
feat = ogr.Feature(featDefn)
nbFeat = layer.GetFeatureCount()

print nbFeat
```

> ERROR Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File "C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Guilhain\Mes documents\My
>   Dropbox\dev\test.py", line 6, in
>   
>       layer = datasource.GetLayer() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has
>   no attribute 'GetLayer'

Comment: Although I doubt it is the cause of your problem, is there any particular reason you are using GDAL 1.6 bindings?  I think you may be better off with 1.7 or even 1.8.  Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 4):

The error you encountered shows that your value for "datasource" is not valid. Instead of using "adresse = 'test.kml'", try entering the full path to the xml file. For example "C:\myfiles\test.kml".

Comment: for Windows paths in Python, you can type this out as `r'C:\myfiles\test.kml'` otherwise the slashes are escaped fror something else.

Comment: No it's not an error, it's a relative path...

Comment: I do that, it doesn't work : `adresse = r'C:/Documents and Settings/Guilhain/Mes documents/My Dropbox/dev/seb_gare/point_station.kml'`

Comment: Are you writing in an IDE that will allow you to step through the code? Take a step back and see if the output of 'datasource = driver.Open(adresse)' is what you want - it appears to be completing this step, but .GetLayer() is not set to operate on the correct input.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to your code to hopefully find out what might be going on with the datasource not being created:

```
ogr.UseExceptions()
```

Comment: It doesn't change

Answer (score 1):

You must provide a name argument to the GetLayer() call, such as datasource.GetLayer("foo"). or use GetLayerByIndex(layer_number_starting_with_0)

Comment: this isn't a problem for 1-layer data sources, as there is a default: [`GetLayer(self, iLayer=0)`](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr-pysrc.html#DataSource.GetLayer)

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but none of the supplied answers appear to fix it. Is your GDAL built with the Expat XML Parser? I see the GDAL docs say that KML read is only supported if GDAL/OGR was built with Expat KML Parser.

Otherwise, only KML Write is supported.